# How to Show $M^2=7M-8I$ if $M$ is given in matrix form

Tags: matrices

$M$ is $2\times 2$ matrix, $m_{11}=3,\   m_{12}=-1,\  m_{21}=-4,\  m_{22}=4$

how to show $M^2=7M-8I$? we can only use substituting or trial and error method or got some more pro method..

Comment: Do you know how to multiply matrices?

Comment: Like a (real) pro: compute the trace and the determinant.

Comment: @Did: that would be great if you could transform your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic equation of $M$ is $$\det(\lambda I-M)=0\\\implies \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda-3 & 1\\
4 & \lambda-4
\end{bmatrix}
\right)=0\\\implies \lambda^2-7\lambda +8=0$$ Now apply [Cayley-Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) theorem.

Answer (score 0):

We're given $$M=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ -4 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$  To verify that $M^2=7M-8I$, we compute
\begin{align*}
M^2 &= M \times M \\
 &= \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ -4 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ -4 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
 &= [???] \\
 &= 7 \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ -4 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix} - 8 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
 &= 7M-8I.
\end{align*}

Comment: This (at most) paraphrases the question (but one needs to actualy look at what is written to see there is no answer here).